# Excel crashing on Save after a Sort

Tags: excel, vba

This just started happening yesterday with an .xlsm file that has a dependency to another .xlsm file.

I can save the file as expected UNTIL I apply a sort - then the save action crashes Excel. It doesn't matter whether I apply the sort by macro or manually.

I have another .xlsm file with the same dependency and I can save it fine after sorting.

Any suggestions appreciated! Version 2016 1611 Build 7571.2072

**Update for Parfait**

The dependency is to a common file that contains macro code as well as data that is made available to Data Validation Lists via defined Names. The sort is applied to a table (ListObject). The files also use custom ribbons, and I have seen these trigger automation errors and security violations that trigger crash behavior.

Comment: Dependency as in macro links, cell references, data source? Sort a table/worksheet/pivot? And sort what? You look to be an avid SO user, surely you know it helps to provide context, data, reproducible example. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: True, true. Maybe you know the feeling where you feel like you are looking for a needle in a haystack though!